# Build Error: Cannot find the class file for org.openqa.selenium.internal.Locatable

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I'm using Selenium and Maven to build a project in Eclipse and I'm getting the build error: Cannot find the class file for org.openqa.selenium.internal.Locatable.

I'm using `Selenium-Server-Standalone 3.141.59`, which I've noticed has the Locatable  class under...

```
org.openqa.selenium.**interactions**.Locatable
```

instead of...

```
org.openqa.selenium.**internal**.Locatable.
```

Is this a different class altogether?

How do I get Eclipse to recognize that the class is there?

Please find followings are my relevant dependencies from my `Pom.xml`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.codeborne/phantomjsdriver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
        <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>               

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `Selenium Server` from your dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
```

If I remember correctly you now need WebDriver, which is included in `Selenium Java`.

Include also `Selenium API`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
```

and update `selenide` and `phantomjsdriver`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
    <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.4</version>
</dependency>
```

---

The current version of `selenide` you're pulling in is `2.3`, which will bring in `selenium-java` `2.33.0`.

The current version of `phantomjsdriver` you're pulling in is `1.3.0`, which will bring in `selenium-java` `2.53.0`.

You need `selenide` `5.1.0` and `phantomjsdriver` `1.4.4`

Comment: I think removing it was the right idea. Unfortunately the error is still there. Any Idea what else could be causing it?

Answer (score 0):

Is it a spring project? What is below solved my problem:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
```